# I cant connect to MySql database Android studio with jdbc

Tags: java, android, mysql, mssql-jdbc

```
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, user, password);
    if (conn != null) {
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    username="dsadsa2";
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (conn != null) {
        try {
            username="dsadsa";
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I trying with this code,

```
databaseURL="jdbc:mysql://DATABASE_IP:3306/DATABASE_NAME"
```

maybe wrong syntax?

Its always get to SQLException and doesnt write in log anything...

Not sure why its happend?

logs

> 03-05 14:18:33.862 8177-8177/com.example.myapplication
>   E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG: I got an error
>       java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273)
>           at com.example.myapplication.VestActivity.onCreate(VestActivity.java:73)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5305)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309) 
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273) 
>           at com.example.myapplication.VestActivity.onCreate(VestActivity.java:73) 
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5305) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>         Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>           at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                 ... 18 more
>        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available 03-05 14:18:33.863
>   8177-8177/com.example.myapplication E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG: I got an error
>       java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:186)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
>           at com.example.myapplication.VestActivity.onCreate(VestActivity.java:79)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5305)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 03-05
>   14:18:33.918 8177-8177/com.example.myapplication E/libEGL:
>   validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do with this: Username="jdbc:mysql://DATABASE_IP:3306/DATABASE_NAME" ?

Comment: please, provide a stacktrace of the exception

Comment: its databaseURL*

Comment: @GoranTerzic that I can see, but why are you assigning it to a username?

Comment: Your posted code doesn't do anything.  Not helpful.

Comment: i write logs...

Comment: @Stultuske writing error

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver -> this says it all, you'll need to add this class to your classpath

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add jtds library in dependencies as,

```
  public class ConnectionClass
{
    Connection con;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection conclass(){
        String ip= "yourip",port="1433",database="DatabaseName",username="username",password="password@123";
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy a=new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(a);
        String connecturl=null;

        try{
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            connecturl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ":" + port + ";databasename=" + database + ";user=" + username + ";"+"password=" + password + ";";
      

           con = DriverManager.getConnection(connecturl);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("Error :", e.getMessage());
        }
    return con;
} 

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).